# Can android get root path of a hard disk with UsbManger and UsbDevice?

Tags: android, usb, device, android-sdcard

I want to get root path of a hard disk, so I write coce as follow:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        UsbDevice usbDevice = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        String deviceName = usbDevice.getDeviceName();
    }
};
```

But I know my `usbDevice` is a hard disk, so I want to get the root path of hard disk, can I get it?

Comment: Did you ever get it?

Comment: @jcaruso I think you can try `String path = intent.getData().getPath();`, it works for me

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getPath()' on a null object reference

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.mobilemerit.usbhost.USB_PERMISSION flg=0x10 (has extras) } in newitventure.filemanagertest.MainActivity$2@392c8ba5